# Postgres: unique on array and varchar column

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.2

I would like to ask if it is possible to set UNIQUE on array column - I need to check array items if are uniqued.

Secondly, I wish to have also second column to be included in this.

To imagine what I need, I'm including example: imagine, you have entries with domains and aliases. Column `domain` is `varchar` having main domain in it, `aliases` is `array` which can be empty. As logical, nothing in column `domain` can be in `aliases` as well as right opposite.

If there is any option how to do it, I would be glad for showing how. And the best will be to include help how to do it in sqlalchemy (table declaration, using in TurboGears).

- Postgresql: 9.2
- sqlalchemy: 0.7

**UPDATE:**

I have found, how to do multi-column unique in sqlalchemy, however it does not work on array:

```
client_table = Table('client', metadata,
    Column('id', types.Integer, autoincrement = True, primary_key = True),
    Column('name', types.String),
    Column('domain', types.String),
    Column('alias', postgresql.ARRAY(types.String)),
    UniqueConstraint('domain', 'alias', name = 'domains')
)
```

Then desc:

```
wb=# \d+ client
                                            Table "public.client"
 Column |        Type         |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Description 
--------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id     | integer             | not null default nextval('client_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 name   | character varying   |                                                     | extended | 
 domain | character varying   | not null                                            | extended | 
 alias  | character varying[] |                                                     | extended | 
Indexes:
    "client_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "domains" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (domain, alias)
```

And select (after test insert):

```
wb=# select * from client;
 id | name  |    domain     |          alias           
----+-------+---------------+--------------------------
  1 | test1 | www.test.com  | {www.test1.com,test.com}
  2 | test2 | www.test1.com | 
  3 | test3 | www.test.com  |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UNIQUE CONSTRAINTs defined over columns that are *not* defined as NOT NULL cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Hm, thank you for good point (`domain` definitelly should be as NOT NULL), however, maybe I have missed something, but NULL values are ommited from unique checking, aren't they? I think I was using this like that in MySQL...

Comment: No, NULLs are unknowns so UNIQUE cannot apply to columns that are not defined as NOT NULL. I've put together a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/22c39/5) to demonstrate this.
 To have the column be nullable, but still have a UNIQUE constraint, you would need to COALESCE the nullable column to a value. Eg. `COALESCE(domain,'xyz')`

Comment: Pity that you have not insert that as a answer, would give you as accepted... After some reading and with your help, I found out that 1. I'm stupind cause unique on more columns is not working for values separately but on combination 2. nullable columns does not respect unique as expected 3. this has to be done programicaly (which is not so big problem, I was thinking this will be "to be sure")... I would leave domain as unique as this is more important column and in case of having same value in alias done by some stupid man here, I would ignore that...

Answer (score 1):

figure out how to do this in pure Postgresql syntax, then use [DDL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html?highlight=ddl#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL) to emit it exactly.

Comment: Thank you for second part of question, would be useful. However, I this don't know how to do it in postgres at all...